# How to calculate totals for each row in a table (rows*columns) structure in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a (simplified) table structure that is defined like this:

```
data class Column<T>(val name: String, val value: T)
data class Row(val data: List<Column<*>>)
data class Grid(val rows: List<Row>)
```

I now want to calculate the totals for each column in that grid, i.e. the `i`th element of each row needs to be accumulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution looks like this. I simply `flatMap` the data and group the column values by the column's name, which I then `fold` to the corresponding sums.

```
 private fun calculateTotals(data: Grid) = data.rows
        .flatMap(Row::data)
        .groupingBy(Column<*>::name)
        .fold(0.0) { accumulator, (_, value) ->
            accumulator + when (value) {
                is Number -> value.toDouble()
                else -> 0.0
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try [sum](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) instead of the more complicated `fold`? To me, a `fold` like this always looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I could not come up with a better solution. I think yours is really good, but I would suggest some syntactic improvements.

1. Use lambda references
2. Use destructuring syntax
3. Don't use `when`, if you only test for one specific type, use the safe cast operator (`as?`), the safe call operator (`?`) and the elvis operator (`:?`).

---

```
private fun calculateTotals(data: GridData) = data.rows
            .flatMap(RowData::data) // 1
            .groupingBy(ColumnsData<*>::column) // 1
            .fold(0.0) { accumulator, (_, value) -> // 2
                accumulator + ((value as? Number)?.toDouble() ?: 0.0) // 3
            }
```